# Controling the clicks in an iframe via Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have this code:

```
$("#iframeID").load(function () {
    var iframeDoc = $('#iframeID').contents().get(0);
    $(iframeDoc).bind('click', function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

and its detecting the click in the iframe, but how can I detect if the click is in for example a javascript function like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="save(100);">save 100</a>
```

I want to detect and get the info of save function via Jquery

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could look for the attribute onclick:

```
$("#iframeID").load(function () {
    var iframeDoc = $('#iframeID').contents().get(0);
    $(iframeDoc).bind('click', function(event) {
        if($(event.target).attr("onclick")) {
            var onclickStr = $(event.target).attr("onclick").toString();
            // containing whatever is inside the onclick attribute, 
            // now you could compare it to whatever you want 
            // might be that you need some kind of regular expression to 
            // etract the function name.
            console.log(onclickStr);

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.on()` event handler.

```
$("#iframeID").load(function () {
    var iframeDoc = $('#iframeID').contents().get(0);
    $(iframeDoc).on('click', 'a[onclick^="save"]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

The first argument is the event, the second is a selector and the third is your anonymous function.

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/bR52H/